# How to Display the multiple new lines on single Text Box in ssrs report

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports

How to reduce the line space on Text Box in ssrs report

i want to single Text Box is multiple New line with same line spacing

But am using the expression  vbcrlf Pls any other idea

Thanks,

Samy

Answer (score 0):

vbCrLf is correct.

Your expression should look something like:

```
="Text goes here." + vbCrLf + "Next line here. " + vbCrLf + Fields!col1.Value
```